# Why doesn't overloading operator new with std::string work with msvc /MD flag

Tags: c++, memory, stdstring

I have some code that looks like this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
void* operator new(std::size_t n){
    std::cout << "[Allocating " << n << "bytes] ";
    return malloc(n);
}

void operator delete(void* pointer) throw() {
    free(pointer);
}

int main(){

    for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++){
        std::cout << i << ": " << std::string(i, '=') << std::endl;
    }

}
```

this compiles and runs using gcc compiler and also runs when using msvc compiler with the flag /MT or /MTd set. however if I set the flag to /MDd or /MD The program crashes. It seems to be stuck in a recursion inside the new operator. Why doesn't this happen when compiling and linking against LIBCMT.lib  which as I can tell from Microsoft docs is the difference between /MT and /MD.

Comment: Why is your `operator delete` marked `throw` and your `operator new` not?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `std::cout`s operator `<<` inside your `new` replacement function. This operator easily might call `new` itself to perform some allocation, in turn, calling your `new` replacement, which would call `<<`, and so on, and so forth.

You should be careful about what you do in those functions. If you want to see how they are called, you can use some preallocated structures and log with them (or simply increment a global counter).

The reason why it happens with one set of flags but not the another is likely due to different allocation strategies employed by `<<` based on those flags. Those would be private to implementation and you shouldn't rely on them.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.